# How to manipulate the value of y in the actuator motion via python?

Tags: python

I am trying to manipulate the *y* value of the "Motion" actuator using python.

**Example**

```
from bge import logic

walk = cont.actuators['Motion']
walk.y = some_value
```

Of course this does not work and was just an example I would like to know of a way to make it work.

Comment: Rules state all posts are written in English, please edit your post and translate it to the required language. If you are unfamiliar with it just use any online translation system

Answer (score 1):

```
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
cont.actuators["Motion"].dLoc = (0, 0.1, 0)
cont.activate(cont.actuators["Motion"])
```

There are 3 important things you are missing.

1. A link to the python API which tells you what all the field names are https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bge.types.KX_ObjectActuator.html?highlight=actuator#bge.types.KX_ObjectActuator.dLoc
2. Setting the entire Vector instead of just 1 channel
3. Activate the actuator afterwards (you can also deactivate it by replacing "activate" with "deactivate")